# need to use the 3rd Party Dll and create WMI Event provider? This gives issue in LoadLibrary

Tags: visual-c++, wmi

need to use the 3rd Party Dll and create WMI Event provider, But the Dll of 3rd Party is not loading by LoadLibrary function But if I use the SetDllDirectory and then use LoadLibrary it works...I don't want to use the SetDllDirectory. How to Avoid the same in VS2019.?

Works:

```
SetDllDirectory(_T(Fullpath));
hDLL_lib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("special.dll"));
```

But

```
hDLL_lib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("special.dll"));
```

doesn't

Comment: You have to tell `LoadLibrary` where to find `special.dll` one way or another. If you don't want to use SetDllDirectory then pass the full path of the .dll into the LoadLibrary call.

Comment: I passed the full length path then also it didn't work.. If I use the combination AddDllDirectory with LoadLIbraryEx then it works..

Comment: If `special.dll` has further dependencies in the same directory you should use `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` flag. If that still doesn't work you'll need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the details.

Comment: i see the 3rd Party Dll is made of C program and my DLL is WMI with C++ will that effect the loading of dll. I used the same which you mentioned..the function call to C program Dll is not returning the correct data..But if I use the Console APP written in C everything is getting printed properly